# Slow 2D animation

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

I'd like to display a complex animation on screen using 2D drawing. Is the following approach the correct one?

1. Creating a timer
2. Do the drawing and invalidating the window inside the timer tick handler

If yes, what happens if the end-user user machine is very slow? Will the list of pending WM_PAINT messages become too long? Will some of them be discarded?

What is the best approach to do 'adaptive-FPS' animations based on the machine speed? Maybe handling the application OnIdle event?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably the best approach is to track how much time passed and update the frame accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on my comment, you probably want an approach where you track how much time has passed, and update the frames accordingly.

I'm assuming you have some function that's called every so often, perhaps from your timer, something like `tick(float elapsedTimeInSeconds)`.

Let's say the value of `elapsedTimeInSeconds` is 0.5, and you display one frame every 0.1 seconds. You would, therefore, skip forward five frames.

Something like this might work for you. AFAIK, this is how a lot of games handle this problem.